# Xalan evaluate xpath with prefix

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xpath, xalan

In my XSLT I have this evaluation statement:

```
<xsl:value-of select="xalan:evaluate('//ns:myNode[1]')"/>
```

but the `ns` prefix declaration cannot be inside the XSLT but it is inside the input XML.

How do I declare something like this:

```
<xsl:declare-namespace prefix="ns" select="/configuration/@myNamespace"/>
```

Comment: Why can't the prefix declaration be in the XSL?

Comment: Because I have an XML that contains a result of a webservice (SOAP) plus an element that should be rendered as an HTML table. That element is something like **<list scan="//webserviceResult/ns:return/ns:items" namespace-prefix="ns" namespace="http://anyurl.com"><col name="description" element="ns:description"> ... **

Comment: You can skip namespaces in XPath using `//[local-name() = myNode][1]` if you need to. But normally you would deal with your namespaces in the XSLT. If you post your full XSL, source and output people here may suggest a better solution.

Comment: I can't use that because there may be nested tags with the same name. Example: **<item><blabla><item><item>...**. Which item should I take?

Comment: Can you add more of your code?

Comment: @Eduardo Your last comment doesn't make any sense. `//*[local-name() = 'myNode'][1]` and `//ns:myNode[1]` are equivalent except that the first one ignores namespaces. What is the scenario here. Are the XPaths being provided by your webservice, or do you have the freedom to write your own. If it's the latter, and it's just a fixed XPath, why are you using `xalan:evaluate()` at all?

Answer (score 0):

The question is vague on some details, so this answer may be addressing an entirely different problem.  I conjecture that

- Your stylesheet is to process input data whose exact form is not specified in full in advance.
- The namespace name and local name of the element(s) to be displayed as a table are not known in advance, but included as part of the document you are processing (returned, as you say, from a SOAP server).  (This is the only plausible reason I can think of for not being able to declare the relevant namespace in your XSLT.  If you have some other reason, please explain.)

If (as suggested by the OP's response to aryn.galadar) the input document specifies the namespace prefix of all relevant elements in `/list/@namespace-prefix`, the namespace name of all relevant elements in `/list/@namespace`, and the QName of all relevant elements in `/list/col/@element`, then there are several ways to retrieve all the relevant elements (or, as suggested in the sample code, the first such element) and get its value:

- Search for elements with the given name:

  ```
  <xsl:variable name="element-name"
                select="/list/col/@element"/>
  <xsl:value-of 
    select="//*[name() = $element-name][1]"/>
  ```
- Search for elements with the given local name and the desired namespace; this protects you against the case where the crucial elements don't actually use the advertised prefix, and is pointless if you don't need such protection:

  ```
  <xsl:variable name="local-name"
    select="substring-after(/list/col/@element, ':')"/>
  <xsl:variable name="ns-name"
    select="/list/@namespace"/>
  <xsl:value-of 
    select="//*
      [namespace-name() = $ns-name]
      [local-name() = $local-name]
      [1]"/>
  ```
- Create a suitable XPath expression and evaluate it:

  ```
  <xsl:variable name="expr"
    select="concat('//', 
                   /list/col/@element,
                   '[1]')"/>
  <xsl:value-of 
    select="xalan:evaluate($expr)"/>
  ```

  The only advantage of this approach is that it provides a use for the reading and experimentation you did while trying to make xalan:evaluate work for you, and thus allows you to save face with your colleagues and/or with yourself.  Otherwise, it's a pointless exercise in taking code that would work in any XSLT processor and replacing it with code that will work only in a processor with an `evaluate` function.